# How to wrap elements based on loop, plus amount of modulus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, modulus

I need to wrap every third instance of a `<div>` in some HTML dynamically, and, if there is a remainder, to wrap that less-than-three amount in a similar manner, so it would serve as the last instance of the "wrap".

Getting every third instance wrapped is pretty basic:

```
var divs = $(".someclass"); 
var limit = 10;
for(var i = 0; i < limit; i+=3) {
    divs.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll("<div class='classwrap'></div>");
}
```

However, because there is a remainder of 1 in this example, and I am otherwise dynamically generating HTML elsewhere (too complex to demo here, but that aspect works fine), the result in this example creates four `.classwrap` `div`s wrapping sets of three `.someclass` `div`s, giving me twelve `.someclass` `div`s, but not ten, however.

What I'm trying to achieve in this example is indeed four sets of `.classwrap` `div`s, but with the first three of those wrapper sets each containing three `.someclass` `div`s, and then getting a fourth `.classwrap` `div` that contains only one `.someclass` `div`, for the grand total of ten `.someclass` `div`s, as indicated by the limit variable.

I have tried to sneak in a modulus operator somewhere in my loop but it always throws off the math and wrapping accordingly.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/44mkp/1/

Comment: The problem is that I am dynamically generating more than 10 instances of the ".someclass" div in the whole HTML and this loop grabs the last two from another group to make 12, not 10. I tried limiting the class via DOM properties, e.g. `$(".superclass > .someclass")`, but no dice. If I could accomplish what I describe, i.e. all the complete groups of three wrapped, and then tack on just the remainder as the last group, I'd be set. I'll never know how many ".someclass" divs there will be, just that I want groups of three wrapped and the remainder as the final wrap, based on the limit variable.

Comment: if you look at my fiddle. I use length instead of hard coded limit. Also, you can loop through your selector list (or view in console) to see why it added the additional two entries.

Comment: I updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/44mkp/2/.  It has two sets of '.someclass' one surrounded by '.super' and the other by a different named class.

Comment: So, by mentioning approaches I abandoned, I wasn't fishing for solutions to them. I abandoned a superclass DOM approach because I don't want to add superfluous classes to accomplish what I seek. I also started with `divs.length` but its value for my page is 190. My `var limit` is also dynamically determined and that's the value I want it to stop at. But rather than stop at 10, as I indicate above, it grabs the next two `.someclass` values to fill out the final loop. That's the problem and what I'm trying to solve: making my `var limit` be the absolute hard stop for the loop, as it is not now.

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle of your rendered html and javascript for this. That way we can see why you are getting more rows than what is being asked for.

Comment: It's pretty extensive and I think I'm being clear about what's occurring and what I'm trying to accomplish. If I can't find any other solution, I will try adding wrapping superclasses as per your example which I'm sure would work but it doesn't seem programmatically necessary -- seems like if I give my loop a limit of 10, I should only generate 3 groups of 3 and 1 group of 1, not reach into another row for the next round of .someclass values (remember, divs.length = 190) to fill out the last group to hit 3, as it is doing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer I think you are looking for.
You need to determine when the last grouping is being made.
then use the modo value to only wrap that many sections.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/44mkp/3/)

```
var divs = $(".someclass"); 
var limit = 10;//divs.length;
var grouper = 3
var modo = limit % grouper;
for(var i = 0; i < limit; i+=grouper) {
    var offset = grouper;
    if(modo + i === limit) {
        offset = modo;
    }
    divs.slice(i, i+offset).wrapAll("<div class='classwrap' style='background-color:#def;'></div>");
}
```

**OR**

replace your initial selection with:
[Fiddle for slice](http://jsfiddle.net/44mkp/4/)

```
var limit = 10;
var divs = $(".someclass").slice(0,limit);
```

Comment: Your first example still returned four groups of three but your slice did it. It actually creates a different problem, in that I now have to find a way iterate over all the 19 groups of 10 -- this just stops after the first 10. But that's a problem I can solve. Thanks for your help!